# Sync google Form via Spreadsheet to Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a survey in a google form which gets stored in a google sheet. From the google sheet data get synchronized with firebase.

I have my trigger "when changes occur" made in the google sheet since my answers are automatically stored in there.
The Problem is, that the trigger does not get called, when a user is submitting the answers.

But if I write directly in the google sheet, my script gets called and data are stored in firebase.

But when I perform my script manually it also gets stored in firebase.

So it basically seems that the google sheet trigger does not get triggered when data are getting passed by the form itself.

Do I have to write a script for the form as well?

This is my script for the sheet:

```
function writeDataToFirebase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

    var timeStamp = data[i][0];
    var uuid = data[i][62];
    dataToImport[timeStamp] = {
      timeStamp:timeStamp,
      uuid:uuid,
      a:data[i][1],
      b:data[i][2],
      c:data[i][3],
      d:data[i][4],
      e:data[i][5],
      f:data[i][6],
      g:data[i][7],
      var1:data[i][8],
      var2:data[i][9],
      var3:data[i][10],
      var4:data[i][11],
      var5:data[i][12],
      var6:data[i][13],
      var7:data[i][14],
      var8:data[i][15],
      var9:data[i][16]

    };
  }
  
  
  var firebaseUrl = "URL" ;
  var secret = "Secret
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret);
  base.setData("", dataToImport);
}
```

Maybe someone can help me how I can fully automate this procedure

Comment: The problem is that all of the triggers that detect some kind of a change only respond to user changes.  So you're going to have to do the data transfer from the onFormSubmit trigger function. And all of the data is easily availabe in the event object of the spreadsheets onFormSubmit trigger

Comment: Just make sure that you add the parameter (I use e) to the function like this: `function onFormSubmit(e){Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` and add that Logger.log and that will give you a direct glimpse of the values that are in the event object.  You can also see some of them [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Thank you cooper! actually changing the trigger to on form submit resolved it.... sometimes it is better to not only got straight forward like in a tutorial and actually read a bit better ;) Could have avoided me some hours of figuring out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Apps Script triggers it is important to keep the following in mind:

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling `Range.setValue()` to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's `onEdit` trigger to run.

The same scenario applies to your situation when using the trigger you chose.

Since you want this function to run *when you receive an answer in your form*, the best approach in this situation is to use an `onFormSubmit` trigger.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).